# How hide alfresco data list?

Tags: java, alfresco, datalistitem

Suppose a data list is created for holding infomation for one workflow. Is is needed to hide this data list - e.g. prevent it from addinig, creating data to it, and more over creating new data list type from UI. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: DataList is a folder containing DataListItems, if you don't need DataList UI there is no reason to use these types. Define your own types inherit directly from `cm:cmobject` (not from folder, content or dataListItem) https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent users from adding, removing and editing data would be to set custom permissions on the datalist items using a java behaviour.